# Ambari installation - jdk issue

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform

I'm using RHEL 6.5 and proceeded as per the [latest documentation](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-1.7.0.0/AMBARI_DOC_SUITE/index.html#Item2.7).

I getting an error(the first time as well as in successive attempts) regarding the jdk installation during the ambari server set-up.

```
ambari-server setup
Using python  /usr/bin/python2.6
Setup ambari-server
Checking SELinux...
SELinux status is 'enabled'
SELinux mode is 'permissive'
WARNING: SELinux is set to 'permissive' mode and temporarily disabled.
OK to continue [y/n] (y)? y
Ambari-server daemon is configured to run under user 'root'. Change this setting [y/n] (n)? n
Adjusting ambari-server permissions and ownership...
Checking firewall...
Checking JDK...
[1] - Oracle JDK 1.7 + Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Policy Files 7
[2] - Oracle JDK 1.6 + Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Policy Files 6
[3] - Custom JDK
==============================================================================
Enter choice (1):1
JDK already exists, using /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz
Installing JDK to /usr/jdk64
Installation of JDK has failed: 'Fatal exception: Installation of JDK returned exit code 2, exit code 2'

JDK found at /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz. Would you like to re-download the JDK [y/n] (y)? y
jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz... 100% (135.8 MB of 135.8 MB)
Successfully re-downloaded JDK distribution to /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz
Installing JDK to /usr/jdk64
Installation of JDK was failed: 'Fatal exception: Installation of JDK returned exit code 2, exit code 2'

ERROR: Exiting with exit code 1.
REASON: Downloading or installing JDK failed: 'Fatal exception: Unable to install JDK. Please remove JDK, file found at /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz and re-run Ambari Server setup, exit code 1'. Exiting.
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue so I went went with the "yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk" option.
1.) Install openjdk: yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk
2.) Tell it to use the openjdk: ambari-server setup -j /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64

Good Luck!